# How to find if file contains date older than X days

Tags: bash, awk

This is my `file.yaml` file:

```
-
    status: Active
    duedate: '2023-09-10'
    notes: "there's nothing important here"
-
    status: Suspended
    duedate: '2023-05-18'
    notes: "some important notes go here"
-
    status: Suspended
    duedate: '2023-09-04'
    notes: "some other important notes go here"
-
    status: Active
    duedate: '2023-10-10'
    notes: "there's nothing here"
-
```

I want to do this:

```
if [ "$(grep -A1 'status: Suspended' file.yaml | awk '/duedate/ {print $2}')" # is 1 day older than today ]
then
    echo "Hear Ye! We have an old duedate here! It is # the actual found duedate"
fi
```

Expected output:

```
Hear Ye! We have an old duedate here! It is 2023-05-18.
Hear Ye! We have an old duedate here! It is 2023-09-04.
```

I'm not sure how to do this, because I'm trying to compare `date` with `date`, and I think `gt`, `ge` cannot do this.

Comment: Related: [How to compare two dates in a shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84381/289373) (Unix & Linux SE).

Comment: Your file seems to be YAML; don't you have any YAML processor like `yq` at hand?

Comment: @JohnBollinger the second answer solved my problem, thanks

Comment: @Fravadona nl I don't have that.

Answer (score 3):

As your input is a YAML file, consider using a command-line YAML processor instead, like [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/), or [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/), or [itchny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq/).

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/) for instance (for [itchny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq/) just change `yq` to `gojq`, and add the `--yaml-input` flag):

```bash
yq -r '.[].duedate | "Hear Ye! We have an old duedate here! It is \(
  select(values < (now | strftime("%F")))
)."' file.yaml
```

```
Hear Ye! We have an old duedate here! It is 2023-05-18.
Hear Ye! We have an old duedate here! It is 2023-09-04.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dates are YYYY-MM-DD format so it is possible to compare them as strings, therefore I propose to harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
-
    status: Active
    duedate: '2023-09-10'
    notes: "there's nothing important here"
-
    status: Suspended
    duedate: '2023-05-18'
    notes: "some important notes go here"
-
    status: Suspended
    duedate: '2023-09-04'
    notes: "some other important notes go here"
-
    status: Active
    duedate: '2023-10-10'
    notes: "there's nothing here"
-
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]";date=strftime("%Y-%m-%d",systime()-1*86400)}NF&&$1<=date' file.txt
```

gives output

```
duedate: '2023-05-18'
duedate: '2023-09-04'
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is 4 digits dash 2 digits dash 2 digits and compute cutoff date using [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) by subtracting 86400 (number of seconds in 24 hours) from current number of seconds since start of epoch and then formatting it same way as in file. Then I find filter which have at least one field (i.e. at least one date) and value of 1st field is less or equal to compute date. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that there will be at most 1 date at each line, if that does not hold ignore this answer.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: That would fail with a false match given input like `notes: "customer ordered this on 2022-10-15"`